# Can i set a group as its own owner?

Tags: permissions

Good evening. I would like to know if i can set, as the owner of a given group, the group itself. For instance: "FooBar Group" owned by.. "FooBar Group". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can go back into the group settings after you have created the group and set the group owner to the group itself.